# Style DataGridView not set

Tags: c#, datagridview

I try to style my form/controls.
For every form I call the `StyleForm(this);` method after the `InitializeComponent();`

```
    public static void StyleForm(Form f)
    {
        f.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(225, 225, 225);
        f.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10);

        foreach (Control control in f.Controls)
        {
            if (control is StatusStrip)
            {
                ((StatusStrip)control).BackColor = Color.FromArgb(93, 107, 153);
                ((StatusStrip)control).Font  = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10);
            }
            if (control is MenuStrip)
            {
                 ((MenuStrip)control).Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10);
            }
            if (control is DataGridView)
            {
                ((DataGridView)control).RowHeadersVisible = false;
                ((DataGridView)control).DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.FromArgb(196, 213, 255);
                ((DataGridView)control).GridColor = Color.Red;
            }
       }
   }
```

For MenuStrip and StatusStrip it is working = the style definition is set.
But for the DataGridView nothing happend.
Why is this not working?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, works for a DataGridView directly on a form but if the DataGridView is not directly on a form it will not work.

Try adding the following class

```
public static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Descendants<T>(this Control control) where T : class
    {
        foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
        {
            if (child is T thisControl)
            {
                yield return (T)thisControl;
            }

            if (child.HasChildren)
            {
                foreach (T descendant in Descendants<T>(child))
                {
                    yield return descendant;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A modified version of your class

```
public static class FormOperations
{
    public static void StyleForm(this Form f)
    {

        f.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(225, 225, 225);
        f.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10);

        foreach (Control control in f.Descendants<Control>())
        {
            switch (control)
            {
                case StatusStrip strip:
                    strip.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(93, 107, 153);
                    strip.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10);
                    break;
                case MenuStrip menuStrip:
                    menuStrip.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10);
                    break;
                case DataGridView view:
                    view.RowHeadersVisible = false;
                    view.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.FromArgb(196, 213, 255);
                    view.GridColor = Color.Red;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.StyleForm();
}
```

I used an existing project as shown below, note buttons and DataGridView

[image]